# How can I clear the Jest cache?

Tags: jestjs

Jest is picking up an old version of a package and thus my tests fail unless I use `--no-cache`. I can even delete the package folder from folder `node_modules` and Jest is happy to run the tests (almost all are passing).

So how do I clear the Jest cache?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can find the cache location by running [`jest --showConfig`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#showconfig). Look for the `cacheDirectory` key. Its value is the name of the folder you'll need to remove.

Comment: is there any reason the cache location should be anywhere outside the project the tests run in?

Comment: @rob why do you expect any reasons from facebook team?

Answer (score 287):

**Just run:**

[`jest --clearCache`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/cli.html#clearcache)

**If you have installed Jest as a dependency** in your Node.js project and the `jest` command doesn't work, just create a new script inside your `package.json` file.

```json
{
    ...
    "scripts:" {
        "clear_jest": "jest --clearCache"
    }
    ...
}
```

And then, run in your terminal:

```
npm run clear_jest
```

---

**With modern NPM, you could also run** *(credits to [johny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866994/how-to-clear-jest-cache#comment91933199_50239754))*:

```
npx jest --clearCache
```

Comment: With modern NPM, you could also run `npx jest --clearCache`

Comment: If you have installed Jest as a dependency, then you likely have added a script to run it.  Assuming that script is named 'test': `npm run test -- --clearCache` willl pass the clearCache flag along.

Comment: This solved my issue - https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/7152. I didnt have direct Jest. Used `npx jest --clearCache`

Answer (score 284):

As of Jest 22.0.0+, you can use the [`--clearCache`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#--clearcache) option:

> Deletes the Jest cache directory and then exits without running tests. Will delete cacheDirectory if the option is passed, or Jest's default cache directory.

Answer (score 67):

First, you need to know the Jest version:

```
yarn jest --version
```

---

**Jest >= 22.0.0**

```
yarn jest --clearCache
```

**Jest < 22.0.0**

```
yarn jest --showConfig | grep cacheDir
```

Returns (you need to remove that folder)

```
      "cacheDirectory": "/tmp/jest_rs",
```

Then, you remove it

```
rm -rf /tmp/jest_rs
```

---

If you don’t use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), do instructions with `npx jest`.

Answer (score 8):

If using nx monorepo run following command to clear the cache

```
nx test <packageName> --clearCache
```