# Karma tests which run to successful completion in Angular 7 (Karma 2.0.4) fail after Angular 8 (Karma 4.1.0) upgrade

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

We have a suite of ~1100 units running in ’ng test’ which currently run to completion in ~4 minutes with no failures in Angular 7.2.5 and fail to run to completion with random failures, slowdown, and disconnect before 4 minutes in Angular 8.0.0.

The tests run successfully in Angular 7 either in Chrome or ChromeHeadless.

Already tried:

1. To eliminate the known memory leak of style elements we implemented “Style Cleanup” [here](https://www.forbes.com/sites/forbesdigitalgroup/2019/05/14/improve-your-angular-jasmine-unit-test-speeds-by-500/#2094768e4163):

by running `cleanStylesFromDOM` in `afterAll` for every describe block in the 1100 tests.

2. In Angular 8 we have tried to regress Karma from 4.1.0 to 3.0.0 and jasmine-core from 3.4.0 to 2.99.1 without success.
3. Tried Angular 8.1.1 with Karma 4.1.0 and jasmine-core 3.4.0 without success.
4. Increased the Karma timeouts:

> browserNoActivityTimeout: 120000,     captureTimeout: 60000,
>   reportSlowerThan: 2000, browserDisconnectTolerance: 2,
>   browserDisconnectTimeout: 20000, browserSocketTimeout: 20000,
>   processKillTimeout: 20000

5. Increased memory to Node.js to `--max_old_space_size=8192`
6. Turned off ‘ng test’ source-map generation and watch
7. Turned off Jasmine random in karma.conf.js: `jasmine: {   
   random: false,   failFast: true,   timeoutInterval: 1000 }`
8. For every ‘it’ in each ‘describe’ block called afterEach with fixture.destroy
9. Tried changing beforeEach TestBed setups to beforeAll as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691705/angular-4-unit-tests-testbed-extremely-slow):

   package.json

   ```
   {
     "name": "myapp",
     "version": "0.0.0",
     "scripts": {
       "ng": "ng",
       "build": "ng build",
       "test": "ng test",
       "lint": "ng lint",
       "e2e": "ng e2e"
     },
     "private": true,
     "dependencies": {
       "@angular/animations": "~8.0.0",
       "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
       "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
       "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
       "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
       "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
       "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
       "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
       "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.20.0",
       "@ngrx/effects": "^8.0.1",
       "@ngrx/entity": "^8.0.1",
       "@ngrx/router-store": "^8.0.1",
       "@ngrx/store": "^8.0.1",
       "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^8.0.1",
       "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
       "angular-resizable-element": "^3.2.4",
       "angular-split": "^3.0.1",
       "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
       "core-js": "^2.6.9",
       "jquery": "^3.3.1",
       "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
       "jquery-ui-bundle": "^1.11.4",
       "jquery.fancytree": "^2.26.0",
       "lodash": "^4.17.11",
       "moment": "^2.17.1",
       "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.2.0",
       "ngx-nvd3": "^1.0.9",
       "ngx-restangular": "^5.0.0-rc1",
       "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
       "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
       "tslib": "^1.9.0",
       "ui-contextmenu": "^1.18.1",
       "urijs": "^1.18.6",
       "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
       "@angular/cli": "~8.0.2",
       "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.0.0",
       "@angular/language-service": "~8.0.0",
       "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
       "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
       "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
       "@types/jquery.fancytree": "^2.7.32",
       "@types/node": "^8.9.5",
       "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
       "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
       "jasmine-marbles": "^0.6.0",
       "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
       "karma": "~4.1.0",
       "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
       "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
       "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
       "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
       "protractor": "~5.4.0",
       "ts-mockito": "^2.3.1",
       "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
       "tslint": "~5.15.0",
       "typescript": "~3.4.3",
       "webpack": "^4.37.0"
     }
   }
   ```

   karma.conf.js

   ```
   module.exports = function (config) {
     config.set({
       basePath: '',
       frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
       browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
       plugins: [
         require('karma-jasmine'),
         require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
         require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
         require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
         require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
       ],
       client: {
         clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
       },
       coverageIstanbulReporter: {
         dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/webr3'),
         reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
         fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
       },
       reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
       port: 9876,
       colors: true,
       logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
       autoWatch: true,
       singleRun: false,
       restartOnFileChange: true
     });
   };
   ```

Example of a test:

```
describe('PageNotFoundComponent', () => {
  let component: PageNotFoundComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PageNotFoundComponent>;
  let selectedTextElement: HTMLElement;
  let router;
  let location;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useClass: WebpackTranslateLoader
          }
        }),
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(
          [
            {
              path: 'basepath',
              redirectTo: 'nwi'
            },
            {
              path: '**',
              component: PageNotFoundComponent
            }
          ]
        ),
      ],
      declarations: [ PageNotFoundComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  afterAll(() => {
    cleanStylesFromDOM();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PageNotFoundComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    location = TestBed.get(Location);
  });

  it('should show 404 text', fakeAsync(() => {
    const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {}
    };
    router.navigate([`/unknown`], navigationExtras);
    tick();
    expect(decodeURI(location.path())).toBe(`/unknown`);
    const textElement: HTMLElement = fixture.nativeElement;
    selectedTextElement = textElement.querySelector('p');
    expect(selectedTextElement.innerText).toEqual('404');
  }));
});
```

We expect the ~1100 tests to run to completion with no failures in Angular 8 as they do in Angular 7.

Here are encountered failures which should not happen:

> Chrome 75.0.3770 (Mac OS X 10.13.6) VMComponent should verify the Vul
>   Suppressions get renders correctly FAILED
>         TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of null
>             at 
>             at UserContext. (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/components/vm-disabled-risk-radius/vm-disabled-risk-radius.component.spec.ts:72:18)
>             at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
>             at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
>             at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:358:1)
>             at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:124:1)
>             at runInTestZone (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:561:1)
>             at UserContext. (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:576:1)
>             at
>
> ... and 20 more random failures
>   and finally disconnects:
>
> 24 07 2019 12:30:11.055:WARN [Chrome 75.0.3770 (Mac OS X 10.13.6)]: Disconnected (0 times)reconnect failed before timeout of 2Chrome 75.0.3770 (Mac OS X 10.13.6) ERROR
>         Disconnected reconnect failed before timeout of 2000ms (transport error)
>       Chrome 75.0.3770 (Mac OS X 10.13.6): Executed 582 of 1134 (20 FAILED) (skipped 3) DISCONNECTED (4 mins 7.005 secs / 3 mins 53.442
>   secs)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? Would like to know, want to implement this in my project as well!

Comment: It's amazing in 1 year nobody has a clue.  A bunch of us at work have this problem.  This really, in my opinion, makes karma an unacceptable tool to use.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the `cleanStylesFromDOM` you mention did, but recently I've encountered a similar issue with a 1800 test large suite. The symptoms were similar:

- Test timeouts towards the end of the run:

```
FAILED
Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)
at <Jasmine>
```

- Perpetually unstable runs in the resource-constrained environments, i.e. CI.

Performance profiling indicated that after each test, the amount of `<style>` tags in the `<head>` steadily increased. The team was not sure if this was the cause, but we decided to address suboptimal resource management as the lead suspect, similar to your `cleanStylesFromDOM`. Fortunately, last year [this PR](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/38336) was merged in, so no additional `afterEach` calls are required anymore. To force Angular clean up after each test, update the test bed initialization in the "test.ts" like so:

```ts
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
  {teardown: {destroyAfterEach: true}}
);
```

`{teardown: {destroyAfterEach: true}}` is the line of interest. Unfortnately, [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/ModuleTeardownOptions#destroyAfterEach) does not say much about `destroyAfterEach`. For me, turning the setting on ultimately lead to stable, always green runs:

1. It unveiled bugs in tests which were masked by resource reuse during individual tests. I was able to reproduce and fix numerous instances of unstable tests locally.
2. No more timeouts, the `<style>`s are cleaned up. Resource consumption went down.
3. The set of unstable tests in CI became stable, I was able to disable these in order to address them later.