# Jest takes a long time to even begin to execute tests

Tags: npm, jestjs

Running Jest (via NPM global install or through a project's node_module binary) takes 5 minutes. To be specific, I'm talking about the time it takes from running jest until the point where it begins to show the test files.

The strange part is that this only seems to happen on the specific model of Mac I'm using (2019 16" MacBook Pro), as it happens to one of my coworkers as well who is on the same model. It didn't happen on my previous computer (2019 15" MacBook Pro), nor does it happen on any of my other coworkers' machines (various 2018-2022 MBPs).

The issue happens with any run of `jest`, not linked to any specific repo.

I've searched for related threads but only seem to be able to locate issues specific to optimizing tests, not with Jest as a whole.

Comment: Try tis. I assume they have same issue as you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087018/jest-simple-tests-are-slow

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the use of barrel files. Jest startup times are slow, because jest traverses every path in barrel files, even if you're not using the export.

This GitHub issue explains it in detail:
https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11234

To summarize the comments, there are a couple of solutions that people have come up with.

1. Execute some pre-run step that replaces all imports in your files with imports directly to files (getting rid of barrel imports). https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11234#issuecomment-1126679867
2. Use esbuild (or some other fast compiler like vite) to bundle all code and unit tests into 1 file. https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/11234#issuecomment-905319778

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the flag `--maxWorkers=1` to the script you run