# How to improve React testing library speed?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I noticed that my first test take like 6 seconds to run, however, it is very simple. It checks whether the Card component renders the passed children successfully:

```
describe('Card component', () => {
  test('renders children', () => {
    const testString = 'TEST';

    const TestCardChild: React.FC = () => {
      return <p>{testString}</p>;
    };

    render(
      <Card>
        <TestCardChild />
      </Card>
    );

    expect(screen.getByText(testString));
  });
});
```

I ran the test on another machine with almost the same specs and it runs in a few miliseconds. Do you have a tip on why this happens? Should I allocate more RAM to VS code, or are there any settings that I should apply for React testing library?

Thanks and regards

Comment: See also [Jest - Simple tests are slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087018/jest-simple-tests-are-slow)

Answer (score 6):

Jest uses [babel-jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-jest) plugin to compile JavaScript code using Babel.

You can find the `ts-jest` process [here](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/processing), it will also use the `babel-jest` processor at the end.

`Babel` is written by JavaScript whose performance is slower than system-level languages such as `Go`, and `Rust`.

The transform process is slow(compared to system-level languages mentioned above), That's why your test suites running slowly.

Now I will use [esbuild-jest](https://github.com/aelbore/esbuild-jest) as jest's transformer. Create two jest config files and compare the time cost.

`jest.config.esbuild.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'esbuild-jest',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-extended'],
  // coverageProvider: 'v8',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.js'],
};
```

`jest.config.rtl.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-extended'],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
};
```

Using `esbuild-jest`:

```bash
> jest --config jest.config.esbuild.js "--no-cache" "/workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/stackoverflow/72897761/routes.test.tsx"

 PASS  stackoverflow/72897761/routes.test.tsx
  first
    ✓ Should test 404 route (32 ms)
    ✓ should render home page (10 ms)
    ✓ should render account detail page (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.457 s
```

**Time: 1.457 s**

Using `ts-jest`:

```bash
> jest --config jest.config.rtl.js "--no-cache" "/workspaces/jest-v26-codelab/stackoverflow/72897761/routes.test.tsx"

 PASS  stackoverflow/72897761/routes.test.tsx (11.246 s)
  first
    ✓ Should test 404 route (32 ms)
    ✓ should render home page (8 ms)
    ✓ should render account detail page (4 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.786 s
```

**Time: 11.786 s**

esbuild is faster than babel because it's written by Go. For more info, see [Why is esbuild fast?](https://esbuild.github.io/faq/#why-is-esbuild-fast)

Jest caches transformed module files to speed up test execution. In order not to affect the test results, we use `--no-cache` option to disable it.

P.S. `ts-jest` may add `esbuild`, see [issue](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/2135). And, take a look at this comment:

> Not there yet, it will be opted in as experimental feature. esbuild doesn't support some TypeScript specific features which we need to be careful with adoption.

Comment: It is absolutely true that Babel is slow to transpile tests. However, this doesn't address the slowness introduced by the React Testing Library. A faster transpiler will make tests run faster, but without RTL in the mix, you wouldn't need it.

Comment: You can check your RTL tests with https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library Note also that the queries byRole are very slow according to: https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/552#issuecomment-992525656

Answer (score 1):

I myself observed performance improved by 4x using [@swc/jest](https://github.com/swc-project/jest) `ts-jest`.
Just run `npm install @swc/jest` and then update your `jest.config.js` file as follow :

```
transform: {
  "^.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": '@swc/jest',
}
```

The downside is that it transforms Typescript code but doesn't do type checking so you will have to do that aside. I found it much faster to do both separately.