# Jest extremely slow on failed tests

Tags: jestjs

I have a jest test file that looks like this:

```
import Client from "socket.io-client"

describe("my awesome project", () => {
    let clientSocket;

    beforeAll((done) => {
        clientSocket = new Client(`http://localhost:3000`);
        clientSocket.on("connect", done);
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        clientSocket.close();
    });

    it("should work", (done) => {
        clientSocket.on("redacted", (message) => {
            expect(2 + 2).toBe(56);
            //expect(message === "foobar").toEqual(true);
            done();
        });
        clientSocket.emit("redacted", "world");
    });
});
```

This is a POC and this currently the entire implementation.

The jest.config looks like this:

```
export default {
  // Automatically clear mock calls, instances, contexts and results before every test
  clearMocks: true,

  // Indicates whether the coverage information should be collected while executing the test
  collectCoverage: true,

  // The directory where Jest should output its coverage files
  coverageDirectory: "coverage",

  // Indicates which provider should be used to instrument code for coverage
  coverageProvider: "v8",

  // A preset that is used as a base for Jest's configuration
  preset: "ts-jest",
};
```

Which is just the file the --intit command generated.

The core of my problem is that any `expect` I use that results in a failed test, no matter how trivial takes an absurd amount of time to complete. I accidentally left it running as above overnight and it eventually completed in 14 hours.

But with a passing test Jest is absolutely fine and completes rapidly.`expect(2 + 2).toBe(4);` for example runs perfectly. On the failed tests I see the data come back from the socket as expected in the time expected. Its only when the `expect` is hit that it stalls out. So I don't believe the problem is in the socket setup or some sort of communication problem.

I've tried the config based solutions I've found to no effect - eg [Jest - Simple tests are slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087018/jest-simple-tests-are-slow)

This is being run on my local windows machine from a terminal I'm fully starting and stopping for each test on my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

OK so now I see the problem, I needed a try catch.

Can't quite believe none of the examples or docs I looked at as much as hinted this is necessary to handle something so basic.

```
test("should work", (done) => {
        clientSocket.on("redacted", (message: string) => {
            try {
                expect(2 + 2).toBe(56);
                //expect(message === "foobar").toEqual(true);
                done();
            } catch (err) {
                done(err)
            }

        });
        clientSocket.emit("redacted", "world");
    });
```

Comment: You save my day. I have the same issue while using the socket together with the jest.
Jest works fine with fail test if the the test doesn't include socket.
But once the socket join in, the fail test will throw an error, and take age to return the result.