# Why would my folder name impact `npm test`, Jest, and Babel?

Tags: babeljs, jestjs, next.js

I'm getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` on my setup file for my Jest tests. I know the fix is via the `.babelrc` file. This actually works in *some* cases. I copy pasted it from https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-jest.

When I run `npm test`, it fails. When I run `npm run test`, it also fails. When I run `npm run test:coverage`, *it works*. My scripts are these:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest",
"test:coverage": "NODE_ENV=test jest  --coverage --coverageDirectory=coverage",
```

If I change `test:coverage` to just `NODE_ENV=test jest`, that fails. So somehow requesting a coverage report magically fixes the issue.

Strangely, the coverage one was failing while the basic one was working. I removed my package lock, removed modules, and tried `npm install` again. Then the fail cases reversed to what I wrote above.

My setup file is this:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import jestFetch from 'jest-fetch-mock';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
global.fetch = jestFetch;
```

I've modified the Nextjs sample app to be nearly identical, yet the error doesn't appear. I have no idea what the difference could be.

**UPDATE**

I literally copied all contents of the sample and it still didn't work. I then RENAMED my folder from `my-app` to `my-appy` and it did work. I went back all my original code, including the folder name `my-app` and it failed. I renamed the folder and it worked. How is the folder impacting what happens when I run `npm test`

**UPDATE 2**

Other people downloading my repo have no issue. Have never run into an issue with a folder name quite like this.

**UPDATE 3**

Cloning to `/Users/dstein/Repositories/my-app` fails. Cloning to `/Users/dstein/my-app` works. Cloning to `/Users/dstein/Repositories/abc/my-app` works. Not sure what could be targeting that one random path to failure, esp given that renaming the folder of `my-app` itself was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about the only thing that could be different on my computer - cache. I tried doing `"test": "NODE_ENV=test BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 jest",` to no avail. I then searched the Jest codebase for the `cache babel` and found https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/6ee2a14b83393c9e3e3408beb5c4848489f04cf6/docs/Troubleshooting.md. Running jest with `--no-cache` had it work. I then found [How to clear Jest cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866994/how-to-clear-jest-cache). So I cleared the cache and the issue went away entirely.

Filed a possible bug or docs issue at https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5796