# Test suite failed to run Cannot find module or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I get the following error every time I try to run test.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/repositories/list_contacts/ListContactRepository.test.ts:4:37 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './ListContactRepository' or its corresponding type declarations.

    4 import {ListContactRepository} from './ListContactRepository';
                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Earlier everything worked fine but this happened after I rename
`src/repositories/quick_contacts/QuickListContactRepository.test.ts` to

`src/repositories/list_contacts/ListContactRepository.test.ts`

And run `git checkout -b list`. After some changes I committed there and come back to previous branch by `git checkout dev` now I face this error whenever I try to run test.

This file `src/repositories/list_contacts/ListContactRepository.test.ts` doesn't even exist on my current branch. But jest keep complaining. Any suggestion to solve this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by clearing [jest cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44866994/how-to-clear-jest-cache) see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50239754/8150077)

Answer (score 7):

In my case I solved the problem by modifying the import path :

import { MyService } from "src/app/mymodule/services/myservice.service";

to

import { MyService } from "../../../mymodule/services/myservice.service";

Comment: you saved me, it was simple as this. any idea why jest cannot figure out the directive @?

Answer (score 1):

by default jest doesn't import files correctly so you have to configure jest to do so

in jest config file
`jest-e2e.json`
you have to add a `moduleNameMapper` json object and specify the importing setting to start from root:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    "~src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
  }
```

after that you need to make sure that jest is applying your modification on jest by clearing the jest cashe

```
npx jest --clearCache
```

finally, rerun your test and it should work

Comment: Also works for the jest.config.js file